# Remove values from all columns and rows of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that look like this

[It is a large dataset with 1500 rows and 200 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZqPM.jpg)

I was wondering how can I remove the number before each value in row and column. example
The values look like this:
1: 0.345
2: -0.467

I want only the value to be like this:
0.345
-0.467

How can I do that?

Comment: Oops, closed by accident.

Comment: Try this: `df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].applymap(lambda x: x.split(':')[-1]).astype(float)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all columns without first by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and for each column `apply` [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and select second value of lists by `[1]`, last cast to `float`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: ['4,8,7', '7,6'], 
                   1: ['1: 0.345', '1: 0.345'], 
                   2: ['2: -0.467', '2: -0.467']})
print (df)
       0         1          2
0  4,8,7  1: 0.345  2: -0.467
1    7,6  1: 0.345  2: -0.467

df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda x: x.str.split(':').str[1]).astype(float)
print (df)
       0      1      2
0  4,8,7  0.345 -0.467
1    7,6  0.345 -0.467
```

If no `NaN`s values is possible use [cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47449222/remove-values-from-all-columns-and-rows-of-pandas-dataframe/47449275#comment81853413_47449222):

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].applymap(lambda x: x.split(':')[-1]).astype(float)
```

Comment: can you pls check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47449545/how-to-split-values-in-a-datacolumn-and-adding-it-to-a-new-column-with-a-conditi

Comment: Thanks your solution worked and thanks for the link :)

Comment: You are welcome! Dont forget upvote solution too. Thanks.