# how to split values in a datacolumn and adding it to a new column with a condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a df,

```
name                        Value
Sri is a cricketer          Sri,is
Ram player                  Ram
Ravi is a singer            is
cricket and foot is ball    and,is,foot
```

and a list,

`my_list=["is", "foot"]`

I am trying to split df["value"] by (,) and adding the value to a new column if the value exists in my_list.
My expected output is

```
name                      Value        my_list
Sri is a cricketer        Sri           is      
Ram player                Ram 
Ravi is a singer                        is     
cricket and foot is ball  and          is,foot
```

please help to achieve this, thanks in advance

Comment: not `and, foot` but `and, is, foot` ?

Comment: yes, sorry. I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with [`str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
my_list=["is", "foot"]
df['my_list'] = df['Value'].str.findall('(' + '|'.join(my_list) + ')').str.join(',')
print (df)
                       name        Value  my_list
0        Sri is a cricketer       Sri,is       is
1                Ram player          Ram         
2          Ravi is a singer           is       is
3  cricket and foot is ball  and,is,foot  is,foot
```

Another solution with [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and get `intersection`s of `set`s:

```
my_list=["is", "foot"]
df['my_list']=df['Value'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: set(x) & set(my_list)).str.join(',')
print (df)
                       name        Value  my_list
0        Sri is a cricketer       Sri,is       is
1                Ram player          Ram         
2          Ravi is a singer           is       is
3  cricket and foot is ball  and,is,foot  is,foot
```

And last:

```
df['Value'] = (df['Value'].str.replace('(' + '|,'.join(my_list) + ')', '')
                          .str.replace('[,]{2,}',',')
                          .str.strip(','))
print (df)
                       name Value  my_list
0        Sri is a cricketer   Sri       is
1                Ram player   Ram         
2          Ravi is a singer             is
3  cricket and foot is ball   and  is,foot
```

Or:

```
my_list=["is", "foot"]

s1 = df['Value'].str.split(',')

df['my_list'] = s1.apply(lambda x: set(x) & set(my_list)).str.join(',')
df['Value'] = s1.apply(lambda x: set(x) - set(my_list)).str.join(',')
print (df)

                       name Value  my_list
0        Sri is a cricketer   Sri       is
1                Ram player   Ram         
2          Ravi is a singer             is
3  cricket and foot is ball   and  is,foot
```

Comment: why ` singeris ` in value 2nd row

Comment: the extracted values should not be present in df["value"] , pls check my expected output